# While loop exits before all conditions are met

Tags: python, jython, oracle12c, wlst

I wrote a script in python to start up servers.
In a loop I'm checking their states, to make sure that all servers are up, before going forward.

But somehow the loop exits before all conditions are met.

Any ideas on why this happens?

```
#check if all servers are RUNNING
while (osb2State!='RUNNING') and (osb3State!='RUNNING') and (osb4State!='RUNNING') and (osb5State!='RUNNING') and (osb6State!='RUNNING') :

    cd('domainRuntime:/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+sOSB2);
    osb2State = cmo.getState();
    if osb2State == 'ADMIN':
        resume(sOSB2);

    cd('domainRuntime:/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+sOSB3);
    osb3State = cmo.getState();
    if osb3State == 'ADMIN':
        resume(sOSB3);

    cd('domainRuntime:/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+sOSB4);
    osb4State = cmo.getState();
    if osb4State == 'ADMIN':
        resume(sOSB4);

    cd('domainRuntime:/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+sOSB5);
    osb5State = cmo.getState();
    if osb5State == 'ADMIN':
        resume(sOSB5);

    cd('domainRuntime:/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/'+sOSB6);
    osb6State = cmo.getState();
    if osb6State == 'ADMIN':
        resume(sOSB6);      

    java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: @abadamso noticed your use of java.lang.Thread, which doesn't seem very like python.  Are you sure you have this tagged right?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: Looks like [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) to me.

Comment: while test should be True as long as all servers are 'RUNNING' so there should be "or" between each test because loop should be looping even if one server is not running, for perfect implementation I'll add a one more variable - loop counter, to exit from this loop and call exception if all servers can't go up in some time or n- loop runs

Answer (score 3):

First, this is Jython not python.

Second take a look at:

```
while (osb2State!='RUNNING') and (osb3State!='RUNNING') and (osb4State!='RUNNING') and (osb5State!='RUNNING') and (osb6State!='RUNNING') :
```

The condition is only True if *none* of the states are == 'RUNNING'. So any server being in a running state will cause the loop to exit. If you want *all* servers to be up before exit, use `or` not `and`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My understanding of Jython is that it is python with java libraries, hence the name Jython. But thanks for highlighting my mistake. Much appreciated!